# Division in python an types

Tags: python

I have a code which part of it looks like this,

```
A=(-1//2+(int(math.sqrt(1+8*t)))//2)
if type(A)==int:
    print(t)
    print(A)
```

The problem arises when I use "/"  to get "A", 
Since I am using "/", I always get an extra decimal point. For example 5/5=1.0 or 4/2=2.0 etc, which python interprets it as a float (I am using 3.6.5). Hence whatever the result is my code stuck at line2.

When I use // the same thing happens. I get 5/2=2 which its float actually but it appears as an integer.

Since my code depends on the type of this division how I can solve this problem?

A=(-1//2+(int(math.sqrt(1+8*t)))//2) its a actually the formula for finding the roots of the quadratic equation (where in the equation a=1 and b=1 and c=-2t for ax^2+bx+c) I need only the integer roots with positive values

Comment: This seems to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If you can explain what you're actually trying to accomplish, we can show you how to do it. If you just show us code you wrote that you don't understand, without explaining what it's for, there's not much we can do.

Comment: A=(-1//2+(int(math.sqrt(1+8*t)))//2) its a actually the formula for finding the roots of the quadratic equation (where in the equation a=1 and b=1 and c=-2t for ax^2+bx+c) I need only the integer roots with positive values

Comment: I can make a guess: You may be asking for [`A.is_integer()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#float.is_integer). But that's probably not a good idea here. If all you're doing is dividing by 2, that's useful and accurate, but as soon as you throw in a `sqrt`, you have to deal with float rounding, and whether the result happens to be an integer or off by a tiny bit is arbitrary. `math.isclose(A, round(A))` might be closer to what you want. See [`isclose`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.isclose) and [`round`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round)

Comment: I edited my post

Comment: I have an idea but I dont know how to do it. When we have 1.0 or 3.0 after the decimal we have 0 but for real floats we have like 3.2 4.5 etc so is there a way to write a code such that "if after the decimal point is 0, take that value" and then I can proceed

Comment: By the way, the quadratic formula can easily have two positive real roots.

Comment: sorry for my case I can have only 1 positive and 1 negative root

Comment: Not quite. If t<0 you get two imagine roots, if t>0 you get positive and negative roots, but if t=0 you get 0 and 1. But you're right that it won't be two positive roots.

Comment: Also you can never have a 2 positive root for positive b.

Comment: Really, so which of the two roots of [-3x^2 +7x -4](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-3x%5E2+%2B+7x+-+4&x=0&y=0) is negative, the 1 or the 4/3? Or is 7 a negative number?

Comment: Its out of discussion but I know enough math for understand these things.I am uni 2 student can you stop arguing please No point to discuss I am talking about for my case when a is positive and c is negative.

Comment: Also -3x^2 +7x -4=0 equals to 3x^2 -7x +4=0, b is negative again

Comment: I dont think you guys fundamentally understand the numeric data types. `3.0` is just as much a "real" float as `3.2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're trying to do won't work. For two integers `x` and `y`, `x/y` is always a `float`, even if it happens to be integral, and `x//y` is always an `int`, even if it has to truncate (throw away) a fractional part. So testing `type(A) == int` doesn't test for anything except which of the two you used.

There is a method [`float.is_integer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#float.is_integer) that you can use, and that works fine for integers divided by 2—but it doesn't work once you're using `sqrt`. Explaining floating-point rounding issues is a big enough job that [it takes up a whole paper that's so important that it's been included by reference in multiple language specifications](http://www.itu.dk/~sestoft/bachelor/IEEE754_article.pdf), but the short version is that `sqrt` could very easily give you a number that's a tiny big bigger or smaller than an integer, so `is_integer` will give you the wrong answer.

What you probably want to do is something like this:

```
if math.isclose(A, round(A)):
```

The [`round`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) function will round a float to the nearest integer. The [`isclose`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.isclose) function will then check whether the resulting integer is "close enough" to the original float. You should read the docs on `isclose` to understand exactly what it does, but in this case, I think the default values will be fine, unless you're dealing with huge integers.

Comment: Well thanks, I ll try to do that and see if it works.

Comment: @ArthurMorgan [Follow this link to see it working](https://repl.it/repls/FavoriteHandsomeGraphics)